# How to make a rank column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, rank

I have a database with columns `M1`, `M2` and `M3`. These M values correspond to the values obtained by each method. My idea is now to make a rank column for each of them. For `M1` and `M2`, the rank will be from the highest value to the lowest value and `M3` in reverse. I made the output table for you to see.

```
df1<-structure(list(M1 = c(400,300, 200, 50), M2 = c(500,200, 10, 100), M3 = c(420,330, 230, 51)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))

> df1
   M1  M2  M3
1 400 500 420
2 300 200 330
3 200 10 230
4  50 100  51
```

**Output**

```
> df1
   M1  rank M2  rank M3 rank
1 400   1   500  1   420  4    
2 300   2   200  2   330  3
3 200   3   10   4   230  2
4  50   4   100  3   51   1
```

**Adjust rankings:**

I used the code, but in a case I'm working on, my rankings looked like this:
[image]

Comment: `df1$rank1 <- order(-df1$M1); df1$rank2 <- order(-df1$M2); df1$rank3 <- order(df$M3)`

Comment: Is M2 in the desired output correct?

Comment: Thanks for the observation @TarJae! I adjusted now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `rank` and `relocate`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(M1:M2, ~ rank(-.x), .names = "{.col}_rank"),
         M3_rank = rank(M3)) %>% 
  relocate(order(colnames(.)))

   M1 M1_rank  M2 M2_rank  M3 M3_rank
1 400       1 500       1 420       4
2 300       2 200       2 330       3
3 200       3  10       4 230       2
4  50       4 100       3  51       1
```

---

If you have duplicate values in your vector, then you have to choose a method for ties. By default, you get the average rank, but you can choose "first".

Another possibility, which is I think what you want to do, is to convert to factor and then to numeric, so that you get a only entire values (not the average).

```r
df1 <- data.frame(M1 = c(400,300, 50, 300))
df1 %>% 
  mutate(M1_rankAverage = rank(-M1),
         M1_rankFirst = rank(-M1, ties.method = "first"),
         M1_unique = as.numeric(as.factor(rank(-M1))))

   M1 M1_rankAverage M1_rankFirst M1_unique
1 400            1.0            1         1
2 300            2.5            2         2
3  50            4.0            4         3
4 300            2.5            3         2
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, that's it. In an example that I'm doing, the rankings were 2.0, 4.5, how can I leave it in the format 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.... Do you know?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How does it those rankings differ from the one you have in the example? Maybe you can update your question and data.

Comment: I inserted in the question a figure that shows the rankings. There must be some way to leave it in the format 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: One doubt: I am using your first code, where could I use `ties.method="first"`?

Comment: In the rank function.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to achieve this result would be to transform each of the df columns into factors, and then convert them into numeric again. This could be accomplished in basic R, but for simplicity I report the tidyverse code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = df1 %>% 
  mutate(Rank1 = as.numeric(as.factor(M1))) %>% 
  mutate(Rank2 = as.numeric(as.factor(M2))) %>% 
  mutate(Rank3 = as.numeric(fct_rev(as.factor(M3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(-3, ~ dense_rank(desc(.x)), .names = "{.col}_rank"),
         across(3, ~ dense_rank(.x), .names = "{.col}_rank")) %>% 
  relocate(sort(names(.)))

#>    M1 M1_rank  M2 M2_rank  M3 M3_rank
#> 1 400       1 500       1 420       4
#> 2 300       2 200       2 330       3
#> 3 200       3  10       4 230       2
#> 4  50       4 100       3  51       1
```